# Trying to write a Trigger to send am email to Case Contact after CaseComment is posted

Tags: apex, trigger, email, case, singleemailmessage

Here is the code I have so far:

I keep getting the error message: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Messaging.sendEmail(Messaging.SingleEmailMessage)

```
trigger EmailCaseOwner on CaseComment (after insert,after update) {
for(CaseComment cc : Trigger.New) {
        String parentID = cc.ParentID; 
        Case newcase = [Select ContactID from Case Where ID = :parentID];
        Contact newcontact = [Select Email from Contact Where ID = :newcase.ContactID];

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            message.setSubject('A new External Case Comment has been posted');
            message.setPlainTextBody(cc.CommentBody);
            message.setToAddresses(new String[] { newcontact.Email });

            Messaging.sendEmail(message);

     }
}
```

Comment: You should also [bulkify](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) your trigger, and that will quite naturally leave you sending a list of emails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From the docs**

> Signature public Messaging.SendEmailResult[]
>   sendEmail(Messaging.Email[] emails, Boolean allOrNothing)

See [Here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm#apex_System_Messaging_sendEmail)

It takes a list of email messages, not a single Email  message.

Just change your code so that you have a list of emails, add your email to that list, and pass that list with only 1 email into the method.

You just need to change one line in your trigger.

**Change this**

```
Messaging.sendEmail(message);
```

**To this**

```
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] {message});
```

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend that since you are sending email to Contacts to use SetTargetObjectId instead of setToaddresses. Sending email by setting SetTOaddresses counts against your daily limits while when using the SetTargetObjectId you don't have limit issues. please also check this for more details http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm